# How to draw a red rectangle around a string of words using pytesseract that has an incorrect spelling

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract, document-layout-analysis

This is my image:

[test2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxwwp.png)

I can recognize the words:

[recognize text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZPUd.png)

I need to check if there is an incorrect word/s
(incorrect spelling) in the text image, highlight this word/s with a red color rectangle and display an "x" above indicating that this is an incorrect word. For example this text image has an incorrect spelling of "worst" -- wort. And then I expect to see:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0WwA.png)

How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread('test2.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)

for i, word in enumerate(data['text']):
    if word != "":
        x, y, w, h = (data['left'][i], data['top'][i], data['width'][i], data['height'][i])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, word, (x, y-4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**UPDATE:**

Updated code showing the number of spelling error in above sentence:

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
from textblob import TextBlob

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

def convert(lst):
    li = list(lst.split(" "))
    return li

img = cv2.imread('test2.png')

lst = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
lst = convert(lst)
mistakes = 0
print(lst)

for x in lst:
  a = TextBlob(x)
  b = a.correct()
  # print(b)
  if (a.correct() != x):
    mistakes = mistakes + 1

print(mistakes)

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)

for i, word in enumerate(data['text']):
    if word != "":
        x, y, w, h = (data['left'][i], data['top'][i], data['width'][i], data['height'][i])
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, word, (x, y-4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 1)
#img = cv2.putText(img, data['text'][i], (x, y+h+20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0,255,0),2 , cv2.LINES_AA)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

```
['It', 'was', 'the', 'best', 'of\ntimes,', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'wort\nof', 'times,', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age\nof', 'wisdom,', 'it', 'was', 'the\n\nage', 'of', 'foolishness...\n']
1
```

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZeYx.png)

Comment: So, you want to check if a word has a spelling mistake, right? That has little to do with Computer Vision, however, you might want to check each word against a dictionary and measure word similarity. Then, depending on the similarity score, identify if a word is correctly spelled. THEN, you might use this information to change the color of the rectangle, but you are missing some essential steps first.

Comment: Drawing a red box in place of a green one is trivial and the only thing related to opencv. The rest of your problem is a tesseract or python issue. So this question seems to me to be a bit out of bounds for this forum.

Comment: @stateMachine I updated my above program with an addition of displaying the output of number of spelling error in the sentence. How can I use this to change the color of the rectangle?